# Fullcalendar refetchEvents

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have the following problem. Sometimes the refetchEvents method works well but sometimes works bad (Slow fetchs). For example sometimes I have to do double click in my button for call this method for render the events correctly from my database. 
So my calendar is not updated correctly when I add a new event.

Answer (score 0):

i would use firebug to see if the ajax requests are the bottleneck, or if it something with the calendar's js. about how many events are you rendering? the problem is likely a slow network connect.

it is not implemented yet, but [this feature request](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=100) might help you out, will prevent the calendar from being editable while ajax is going. you can star it if you'd like to receive updates.